# Kubernetes Azure.. Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When I am in the office, I can connect to my Kubernetes cluster that is on my Azure account without an issue.

At home, on my home network or connected to my corporate VPN, all worked until a couple days ago.  All of a sudden, I'd get either:

Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (mostly)
or
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

On every KUBECTL command (kubectl get pod for example)

Is there any reason why this would happen and depend on the network I'm connected to?  With VPN, I have access to the same resources.

I'm using a Windows 10 machine and I'm using powershell to connect to the cluster.

Comment: It's not dependent on the network, it's dependent on the certificates that your TLS stack trusts. On your work computer, you likely added some kind of CA certificate to your trusted certificates. I know little about Windows, but that's the first place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.   It's the same computer in both cases....  Its just whether I'm connected to my home network or work network that changes.   I tried a 3rd network, and I had problems there too....

Comment: Could your home network internal IP range overlap with that of your Kubernetes cluster in Azure?

Comment: We determined this morning it’s something with two he proxy my office sets up that controls where we can go when we aren’t on the corporate network.  Sounds like something changed which effected me so they added azmk8s to the whitelist and now it seems to work.